# Suggest me a great customer support web application. Like Github support

Tags: customer-service

I am looking for a customer service solution. Managed. Paying is not a problem.

I like these two solution, and look the same to me:

http://support.mongohq.com/

http://support.github.com/

Do you know what are they using?

Can you provide a different and better alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your examples above use [Tender](http://tenderapp.com/) from a company called [entp](http://entp.com/). You could also try [Zendesk](http://www.zendesk.com/) which is used by companies such as Twitter. If you wanted to go down the more community route, you could use [Get Satisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/).

Comment: Great suggestions. Another support system that is more social-network-based is [Assistly](http://assistly.com).

Comment: We are also working on a cheaper Zendesk alternative, check it out [Jitbit Helpdesk](https://www.jitbit.com/) Disclaimer: I'm involved with the project